# Cannot create new object in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am just learning mongodb and I can't understand why I cannot create a new object.

I am trying to create a new object in "Chat" collection using params to push userIds into the "users" array.

The error I am getting is: "POST /api/chat/add/5f14bb0564d9783290b54bb8/5f14c0992a9ef9454076d0fc 500 3.899 ms - 2494
TypeError: Chat.insert is not a function"

Models:

```
const chatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    users: [{
        type: String
    }]
}, {timestamps: true})

module.exports = mongoose.model("chat", chatSchema);
```

routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const {loadRooms, createChat} = require ('../controllers/chat')

router.get('/chats/:userId', loadRooms);
router.post('/chat/add/:userId/:contactId', createChat);

module.exports = router;
```

controller:

```
exports.createChat = (req, res) => {
    Chat.insert({users: [req.params.userId, req.params.contactId]}, 
        (err, chat) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: errorHandler(err)
            })
        }
        res.json(chat)
    })       
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry, I have edited just now!

Comment: The error message tells you that there is no `insert` method - check the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) again, there is no `insert` static method on Mongoose models (only `insertMany` but that's not what you want)! There is, however, `create`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will be something like this

```js
let createdObj=new Chat({users: [req.params.userId, req.params.contactId]});
createdObj.save().then(data=>{}).catch(err=>{});
```

this if you want to work with mongoose model.
if you want to work with native API it will something like this (I am not sure of syntax) 
`Chat.collection.insertOne`